# Find all XPaths of button and chose the last one?

Tags: ruby, xpath, cucumber, capybara

I've a table with four columns and growing number of rows. Every time I test, I need to apply the test on the last row, that I don't know its XPath because it wasn't there when I wrote the test the first time.

The XPath that I need will be like:

```
//*[@id="example"]/div/table/tbody/tr[X]/td[4]/a[1]
```

with variable `X`.

Is there a way to to scrap the `X` value and chose the maximum no of it, or something like that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking about code, we need to see a minimal example of your input data, and the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem. Without that we have to take time to cobble up both. That can result in errors or misunderstandings, which only frustrate both of us and delay you getting an answer. So, help us help you and provide the necessary input and code. See "[ask]" for more information.

Comment: The idea, when testing, is to use a small, well known input, not something that continues to grow. If it continues to grow your test times increase, eventually beyond the patience of those working on the code and running them. Also, don't rely on an explicit path. Find known way-points in the markup, typically a parent node, then find the children you actually need and select the last one. It takes two steps but it removes the need to generate an explicit XPath or CSS selector.

Comment: Thank You, I Will try to be more clear next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
//*[@id="example"]/div/table/tbody/tr[last()]/td[4]/a[1]
```

This will select the first anchor tag from the fourth `td` element of the last table row, as required.

Comment: `find(:xpath, '//*@id="data_main_container"]/div/table/tbody/tr[last()]/td[1]/a[2]').click` , didn't work , and respond with _Capybara::ElementNotFound_.

Comment: no unfortunately, i can't, but i tried exactly this line with a real number instead of last() and worked fine !

Comment: The` tr[last()]` will select the last row - not the last row with an a element in the 4th td -- so if the last row happens to not have 4 tds with an a in the last of them it will give the error mentioned -- is that the case ?? ie- do you have a footer row or something in the table? Providing actual html would help

Comment: apparently, there is a hidden row in the bottom of the table or something like that, because when i used `tr[last()-1]` it worked fine, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution for this would probably be

```
all(:xpath, '//*[@id="example"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/a[1]', minimum: 1).last
```

or

```
all('#example div table tr td:nth-of-type(4) a:first-of-type', minimum: 1).last
```

Note: the `minimum: 1` forces `#all` to use Capybaras waiting behavior to wait for at least 1 matching element like `#find` normally does